# How to get the UWP AppPackageID by ProcessID

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to get the Application Package ID (i.e. the ID of an UWP app) by only providing the PID of a process.

Some background:
I have a small app that shows connections blocked by the windows firewall, and I would like to show not only the process name but if the process hosts UWP Apps (or PWAs) the name of the Application package.

Comment: sorry I meant ID

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the package family name like `YourAppName_1.0.0.1_x64__by20zvz6wrq60`, you can parse it from the full path to the main module of the process, which is in the form of *C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\YourAppName_1.0.0.1_x64__by20zvz6wrq60\SomeApp.exe*.

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(21576); //provide the correct process Id
if (p != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.MainModule.FileName); 
}
```

Note: Compile your small app as a 64-bit program, so it can query both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

Comment: Would that be 100% reliable? isn't there a more proper way of getting the App package ID?

Comment: For listing all UWP packages, you may find [PackageManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager) useful. But in this case, all you have is the id of some running processes. I test the code with a few UWP apps and the result is correct.

Comment: With `PackageManager class`, you can get each package's id as well as the install location, and you can compare the install location against the `MainModule.FileName`; That way you are more confident comparing to using just string parsing.